# What is the name of this plant and how should I plant and care for it?

Tags: identification, houseplants

I bought a plant without a name tag (in the picture). I'm guessing that it might be a Pothos, but I wasn't sure. What is the name of this plant and how should I plant and care for it? I plan to grow it in my apartment room.

[image: Plant]

Answer (score 5):

This plant is a [Dieffenbachia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dieffenbachia), a member of the Arum family which includes the Spathiphyllum and Anthurium.

The care conditions are:

- bright diffuse limit
- keep a little moister than you would normally
- under low light conditions this plant stretches out and flops, do not be afraid to cut the stem back to just a few inches above the soil as new growth will bud easily

The major claim to fame this plant has is that it has been described as fatally poisonous due to presence of oxalic acid in the leaves. Yet if you actually look for statistics on fatalities from houseplants it's hard to find much. [This site](http://www.hoax-slayer.com/killer-house-plant-warning.shtml) has more details.

Do not let anyone or any pet eat any part of this plant or they will get minor irritation.  With any toxicity claims the amount you ingest is as important as what.  Stick with salads...

Answer (score 4):

You have an Aglaonema - common name Chinese Evergreen. There are many different varieties.

It is a hardy plant, that's easy to keep. It likes to be indoors, can tolerate low light and doesn't like to be overwatered.

Detailed information on caring for it can be found here at [Gardeningknowhow](http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/houseplants/chinese-evergreen/chinese-evergreen-plants.htm).